# How to change the font and size of a subheading in vba outlook code using html

Tags: vba, outlook

```
consolidatedContent = consolidatedContent & "<h2>" & subject & "</h2>" & vbCrLf & tableContent & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

I have the following code but i only want to change the font of the subject that is within the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
consolidatedContent = consolidatedContent & "<h2 style='font-size:20pt'>" & _
         subject & "</h2>" & vbCrLf & tableContent & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

for example